# Primitive polynomial over $GF(2^n)$ with $n>1$

Tags: finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

I need at least two primitive polynomials over $GF(2^n)$ (with $n>1$). All the articles I've found only primitive polynomials over $GF(p)$, never over $GF(p^n)$.

Does it exist some tables of such polynomials or algorithms generating them?

Answer (score 0):

YES.
i've tried this on SAGE witch kind of work

```
K.<a>=GF (4)
R.<x>=K[]
V = R.irreducible_element(5);V
V.is_primitive();
```

and it gave me

```
x^5 + x^4 + (a + 1)*x^3 + a*x^2 + x + a + 1
```

of cours 'a' is a root of

x^2 + x + 1